# Check if user is signed in on PrivateRoute component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making my first react app with user authentication on my Rails Api (DoorKeeper/Devise). I set the `expires_at` in react's `local_storage` and try to verify in the private route component. I want to verify a user token to give him access to routes in this case '/'. I cant reach userSignedIn. how do I reach this function from the PrivateRoute component?

```
// PrivateRoute.js
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import userSignedIn from '../auth'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    userSignedIn === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
  )} />
)

export default PrivateRoute;
```

```
// auth.js
const userSignedIn = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('expires_at') !== null) {
    return new Date() < new Date(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'))
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

export default userSignedIn;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't had time to test this but

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    userSignedIn() === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
  )} />
)
```

You need to call the function `userSignedIn()` since it's what returns the value `true/false` (that's the only change here) `userSignedIn === true` -> `userSignedIn() === true`

Comment: Thanks I’ll test in and let you know

Comment: Yep that was it LOL